# Offsets of csv file when accessing through php?

Tags: php, csv, offset, fgetcsv

I have a small doubt regarding the offsets. Suppose I have a csv file like this:

1
8   9   10  11  12  13  14
15  16  17  18  19  20

I am simply using fgetcsv function to retrieve data from csv to my php page. Here's the code:
    $fp = FOPEN ("so-csv.csv","r");
    $data = FGETCSV ($fp, 1000, ",")
    symbol 
    date
     .
     .
     .

data[0] shows "1" but data[1] is undefined offset. var_dump($data[1]) displays NULL. I believe I am accessing row-1 col-B of csv through data[1] which is null. How do I access next row (element 8)? Thnx

Answer (score 1):

```
while($data = fgetcsv($fp,1000, ",")) {
    // your processing code here
}
```

that's all you should need

Comment: Still can't get it done. Undefined offset error still persists. Can you tell me if there's a naming convention for the example data in csv file given in question??

Comment: I would assume that your numbers are separated by commas... which isn't the case in your example.

Comment: Also, `$data[1]` does not exist for each `$data` reference. The first row will have `$data[1]` undefined, and the second row will have `$data[1] = 9`

Answer (score 0):

The fgetcsv function only reads in one line at a time. To get the second line of the file, you simply need to call the function a second time.